# React.js run useEffect before useState set default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have react componet called employee.js. I use this component to create employees and update employees.
I manage a state called `isUpdate`.

With the help of the `useEffect` hook I change `isUpdate=true`. Which means this component works as an update component. Default value for `isUpdate` is false.

I use formik to do the validation part.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (props.location.state && props.location.state.update) {
            // update
                        
            console.log('line 1')
            
            getEmp(props.location.state.id);
            
            console.log('line 2')
        }
    }, [props.location.state, console.log('initial values', initialValues)]);
```

This is my `useEffect` hook's code. Please note the console logs "line 1" "line 2" and the "initial values" one.

My problem is initial values are printed even before the `line 1`. So at that time initial values are empty. But these values are set to the formik form. Even after the initial values changes it doesn't reflect in the UI.

I came from vuejs world and new to react. In vuejs it had created life cycle hook. It runs before any thing. Here component seems loading even before the useEffect hook.

How can I fix this in react world?

Comment: Can you show your entire component or more of it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're logging `initialValues` just to check what it is...but you're doing it inside the dependencies array.  why?  Also, what is `initialValues`, and where is it being used?

Comment: your second parameter in the useEffect hook is NOT supposed to be used like that. that is the dependency array, which will only react to changes in a certain state or prop. do not put `console.log` in there

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` is run after the DOM is created and the render has been committed to the screen. So if you are wanting to do something before the render, you'll want to look at `useLayoutEffect`. Most of the time, `useEffect` is what you need and you just need to account for asynchronous data flow.

`useEffect` will run every render unless you provide a dependency array. If you provide a dependency array, `useEffect` will only run the first time, and everytime that array of values changes (not the array itself as its memory address will change every render usually). I believe it performs a shallow comparison, so you'll want to be careful about using objects in the dependency list (mutable.js is great for this).

With those two pieces of information, you can see why your code is a bit odd.

You call `useEffect` with the function to run and a dependency list of `[props.state.location, console.log(...)]`, which means `useEffect` will run the first time, and anytime `props.state.location` changes. It looks like its an object, so whenever that object's memory address changes. The second parameter will always be undefined and therefore is not really useful in this context.

You call out that the log happens before the `useEffect` function runs. This makes sense since its a parameter to `useEffect`, and parameters have to be evaluated before the `useEffect` method can be invoked.

Let's revisit your question. It sounds like you are using something called Formik that is being set on `initialValues` however its happening after the first render, and isn't triggering a new render? I'd need to see more code related to `initialValues` but here's my guess. You are probably setting a value directly on `initialValues` instead of doing it via `useState`. React needs to know when to re-render a component and it does this by listening for `setState` calls. It does not do smart magical stuff like Mobx or VueJS, and therefore can't magically re-render itself when you change a property somewhere on state.

```
// Creates a state variable called isUpdate and initializes it to false.
// On re-renders, it provides isUpdate with whatever value its been updated to
const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState(false);

// Sometime in the future

// changes state and causes a component to re-render
setIsUpdate(true);
```